# How to handle nested form tags with lxml

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

I want to scrape some html pages that have nested form elements with lxml. Even BeautifulSoup chokes on these pages, the only parser I've found that can handle them so far is MinimalSoup which has no knowledge of which tags can be nested or not.

Does lxml have any parsers that don't care about about nested form tags?
Any other suggestions?

If I have to I'll just continue using MinimalSoup.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page you are trying to scrape, and say what is the data you are having troubles reaching?

Comment: the pages require login so I can't provide a link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about lxml.etree.HTMLParser?  That should work relatively well, right?

```
import urllib2
import lxml.etree as etree
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.parse(page,parser)
```

And you have your tree!